# Plotly Scatterplot from CSV in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

I am new to javascript/html and am trying to learn how to plot a scatterplot from a CSV file with 2 rows(Year,January), mapping some temperature data. I have the following Code written but I am not seeing anything. I think maybe my svg elements are wrong? I hope someone can help.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"'></script>

        <script>
            var d3 = Plotly.d3
        

            function drawfromcsv(){
                d3.csv("NOAAData.csv", function(err,rows){
                    function unpack(rows,key){
                        return rows.map(function(row){ return row[key];})
                    }

                    let data = [{
                        type:"scatter",
                        name:"Data",
                        x:unpack(rows,'Year'),
                        y:unpack(rows,'January'),
                    }]
                    
                    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',data,layout)

                    


                
                })
            }
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b>First name,last name ,student number
        <b>Course:</b> Course Number</p>
        <h1>Attributes</h1>
        <p>
            This assignment uses the plotly.js library to graph global temperature data that is taken from the <href a="https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cag/" NOAA Climate at a Glance></href> website.<br>

        </p>
        <div width=500 height=500 style="float:left">
        <svg id="myDiv"></svg></div>
        <div id='myDiv' width=500 height=500 style="float:right">
        </div>
    </body>
```